# Create .key file knowing the key code of digital signature

Tags: certificate, digital-signature, pfx

I need to create a .pfx file starting from the digital signature contained in a smart card.
I have a smart card and I know the key code that allow me to create a .cer file, but not the .pfx. I tried using the "OpenSSL" utility but what I miss is the ".key" file.
How can I generate the .key file knowing the key code of the smart card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be doing something here that you don't really want to do. Creating a certificate (the .cer file you mentioned) is a normal use case with smart cards where you use the smart card to sign that certificate. You don't get the "key file" because that's secured in your smart card.

In typical cryptographic smart cards you cannot export the key as this would invalidate the whole idea of having it physically protected.

PFX file as well as pkcs#12 container both include a certificate and the private key in the same container. And as you most likely cannot export your key from your smart card, what you are asking is not possible.